# Problemas con el IIS y la base de datos

Tags: sql, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

Hace algunos dias publique mi aplicacion MVC + AngularJs  en IIS. Todo funciona bien excepto la base de datos, no quieren funcionar las peticiones GET, ECT...

Me lanza la siguiente exepcion:

> This Request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to thir party web sistes when this is use in a Get Request. to allow Get Request, set JsonRequestBehavion to allow get

Esta es la conexion en mi appconfig:

```
data source=10.xx.xx.93,1433;initial catalog=TrackingSystem;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework
```

Y este es mi controlador :

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetData(String St)
{
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now);
    try
    {
        HandlingUnitRepository ZH = new HandlingUnitRepository();
        return Json(ZH.GetData(St), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch
    {
        return Json("Error al intentar obtener la data!");
    }
```

Mi petición en angularjs:

```
$scope.GetData = function (select) {
    $scope.Loading = true;

    //Peticion Get para obtener el listado de ZourfReport
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8082/HandlingUnit/GetData?St=" + select,

    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        $scope.Data = response.data;
        $scope.Data.DateShipped;

    }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.Data = response.statusText;
    });
```

Comment: Es porque tienes la cadena de conexión en modo trusted connection (integrated security=True) y seguramente la aplicación en IIS la usas bajo App Pool.
Así que te toca agregar el usuario IIS a la base de datos (IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool que en SQL es la cuenta NT AUTHORITY\IUSR) o agregar al web.config del IIS un usuario válido para SQL.

Answer (score 1):

La función esta entrando en el `catch` por algun error y en el catch no estas habilitando las peticiones `get`, lo cual están bloqueadas por defecto en la versión de MVC que estas utilizando

Cambia la sentencia a

```
return Json("Error al intentar obtener la data!", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

saludos

Comment: Ok muchas gracias lo arregle y ahora me lanza el siguiente Error: 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'.

Comment: @AlejandroMst la respuesta de Mauro realmente soluciona tu problema, considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada ;) El problema que ahora se te presenta es debido a que necesitas agregar el usuario `IUSR` a los logins de tu base de datos, esto porque es el usuario por default que usa el IIS y de igual forma requiere privilegios para acceder a la base de datos.